# AC induction motor circuit and stall current

Tags: motor, induction-motor

How can I describe the stator current of a 3-phase locked/stalled induction motor by using equivalent circuit of the motor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slip at locked rotor is 1, so the rotor resistance and reactance are connected directly to neutral for the per phase model.

[image]

Diagram from Fizgarald Kingsley Umans "Electric Machinery" 4th ed

Comment: could you illustrate and quantify it on the diagram?

Comment: I have added a diagram.

Comment: thanks do you think in this situation the motor gets harmed?

Comment: A motor will be damaged if it remains at locked rotor for more than a few seconds at rated voltage.

Comment: That is based on a squirrel cage induction motor of a usual design. A motor with a high resistance rotor could tolerate full-voltage locked roter a little longer.

Comment: is that because s becomes 1? would the stator windings burn in that case?

Comment: With S = 1, the stator and rotor currents are very high. In addition, the rotor at standstill is not moving air through or over the outer surface to cool it. Both stator and rotor will overheat.